# Prestashop add voucher to the database from custom module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a custom module in Prestashop 1.6 . I want to create voucher and save them in the database so that one can use that from my module. So can someon tell me what is the function for adding vouchers to the database? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Normally, you would use PrestaShop classes such as `CartRuleCore`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I didn't try it but it shows how to easily use PrestaShop classes to add objects to the database

```
$cart_rule = new CartRule();
$cart_rule->name = 'xx';
$cart_rule->product_restriction
$cart_rule->quantity = xx;
$cart_rule->id_customer = xx;
$cart_rule->code = 'xx';
$cart_rule->active = 1;
$cart_rule->reduction_percent = 20;
$cart_rule->free_shipping = true;
$cart_rule->save();
```